# Why elasticsearch process killed when I start another one?, even if it from other directory?

Tags: java, linux, ubuntu, elasticsearch, command-line

I run this command

```
Elastic-1/bin/elasticsearch
```

from the first directory and it works.

Then I tried to open another node from another directory like so

```
Elastic-2/bin/elasticsearch
```

the first process killed

How can I fix this problem?